Calling uwp library from unreal engine
I'm trying to use an sdk that is built for .NetCore which I got from Nuget. Since, I can't directly use it in Unreal Engine 4 (.NetFramework), I've made a UWP C# Class library as a wrapper, and I'm using a C++/CTL class library as a mediator between my unreal code and the library.
The issue is that when a call goes to the function that has the actual reference to the library (in the wrapper) it gives me a "EEFileLoadException".
I don't understand why that is the case.
Is it completely not possible to use wrappers to access .netcore functionality from an app based on .netframework?
Is there any other way that this is meant to be done?
I've made sure that all my references are set up properly. My C# class library has a reference to the package that I need, My mediator layer has the dll exported from the wrapper as a reference and I'm able to call the functions, but still I get this error when trying to use the actual classes I need in the nuget library.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

UWP plays in a sandbox; I can't see why a UWP class library (which I use) wouldn't either. I use ".NET Standard" libraries to share code between Console, WPF and UWP; which wouldn't include UI elements.

So, the reason why I was getting the EEFileLoadException was that I did not properly export the class library as the dll was on debug mode. Fixed that issue, but now I'm getting an HRException, not sure what that means and I'm currently in the middle of figuring it out, but if you've faced the same issue by any chance, please point me in the right direction.
Also, @GerrySchmitz, have you made a 'self contained deployment' for the uwp library? I don't want the user to have to install .netcore on their system, and I want all the necessary .netcore dlls packaged with my output executable.

My apps are deployed via MS Store; and I have no issue bundling UWP exe, UWP dll, and  Standard dll. (I can't picture a case where I only give someone a "library") BTW, you can call into an EXE just as you can call into a dll; but all still have to be compatible. I can also deply my apps to my own remote devices via VS. The Windows Certification tests tell you when you're good to go. I hear "foreign" (i.e. "3rd party") dll's are an issue when it comes to certification.
